# Using golang-ci lint error fetch corp package

Tags: go

Im using golangci-lint and getting the following error in CI, any idea what could be the reason? and how can I avoid this.

Our GitHub repo is already **have all the vendor packages** so it shouldn't install it in first place.

> golangci-lint run --config golangci.yml
> level=error msg="Running error: context loading failed: failed to load packages: failed to load with go/packages: err: exit
> status 1: stderr: go: github.avt.corp/ding/logger-ut@v1.1.0:
> unrecognized import path "github.avt.corp/ding/logger-ut" (https
> fetch: Get https://github.avt.corp/ding/logger-ut?go-get=1: x509:
> certificate signed by unknown authority)\n"

btw I was able to clone the project and run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
run:
  modules-download-mode: vendor
```

or add this to the command you are runnig

```
--modules-download-mode vendor
```